# Does Java 7 support simultaneous horizontal + vertical scrolling for trackpads?

Tags: java

### Possibly related info:

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10. Both vertical and horizontal scrolling work in my firefox window (thus, the problem is not the kernel / OSX).

### Problem

In Java7, I want to get both horizontal and vertical scrolling to simultaneously work in my awt/swing app.

If I use MouseWheelListener, I only get vertical events. (I don't get the "shifted" events that represent horizontal scrolls.)

If I use ScrollPane, only vertical scrolling works. I can't horizontal scroll.

### Question:

What do I need to do in order to get horizontal + vertical scrolling to simultaneously work in Java 7?

Note: "it can't be done is not an acceptable answer." I'm looking for instructions on recompiling the JVM if necessary, or getting raw trackpad events if that's easier.

Comment: So [JScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(int)) does not work?

Comment: When I set horizontal and vertical bar both to _ALWAYS, the vertical one takes precedence, and mouse pad movement only scrolls vertically. (I can scroll horizotnaly by dragging the horizontal scroll bar, but not via mouse pad.)